# Order of Magnitude of $\log{n!}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, logarithms, asymptotics, approximation

In their proof that $\log{n!}$ and $n\log{n}$ are asymptotically equivalent, Courant and Robbins derive the inequality $$L=1 - \frac{1}{\log{n}} + \frac{1}{n\log{n}}\lt \frac{\log{n!}}{n\log{n}} \lt \left(1+ \frac{1}{n}\right)\frac{\log{n}+\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) }{\log{n}}-\frac{1}{\log{n}}=U. $$

They then set the following exercise:

> Prove that the two bounds are greater than $1-\frac{1}{n}$ and less than $1+ \frac{1}{n}$ respectively.

I interpreted this as asking us to prove $1-\frac{1}{n} \lt L$ and $ U \lt 1+\frac{1}{n}$, but, evaluating for specific (large) $n$, I found $1-\frac{1}{n} \gt L$, and thus I am unsure exactly what the question is asking us to prove?

Edit: Since @NN2 said the result holds asymptotically, I tried to evaluate the difference $$\left( 1-\frac{1}{n}\right) - L = \frac{1}{\log{n}} - \frac{1}{n\log{n}} - \frac{1}{n}.\tag{1}$$ By definition $\log{n} = x \iff e^x = n$. Substituting this into $(1)$, $$\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{xe^x}-\frac{1}{e^x}=\frac{e^x - (1+x)}{xe^x}\gt 0$$ for all $x\gt 0$, so again it seems like this isn’t the result the problem wants us to prove.

Comment: The inequalities hold true **asymptotically**. In other words, $n$ should be sufficiently large.

Comment: @NN2 can you give an $n$ for which $L>1-\frac1n$ ?

Comment: It could be better to say something like $1- \dfrac{1}{\log n} \lt \dfrac{\log{n!}}{n\log{n}} \lt 1$ for $n\ge 2$

Comment: As Henry points out $L < 1-\frac1n$ for all $n$, and in fact $L$ converges to $1$ signficantly more slowly . There is probably some typo in the formula for $L$. You might want to comb through the proof of the inequality to see if they actually are proving something a little different.

Comment: Log of products is sum of log of things being multiplied. The maximum for each in $n!$ is $\log n$  and it in theory could be every entry so we get $n\log n$